# What is Plo Koon's real face?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, the-phantom-menace, attack-of-the-clones

Everyone has a face behind their mask, even Vader. What is Plo Koon's? Has anyone ever seen it, behind those eye-patches and breathing apparatus?

[image]

Comment: That's a mask!?!

Answer (score 17):

He hasn't been shown without his mask in the new canon, but we have seen his bare face in Legends.

From *[Star Wars: Purge: Seconds to Die](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Purge:_Seconds_to_Die)*:

[image: Plo Koon maskless]

[A 2010 action-figure](http://tvandfilmtoys.com/index.php/2010/05/plo-koon/) gives him the same appearance.

[image: Plo Koon maskless action figure]

Comment: It looks like an unmasking of a Predator to me lol

Comment: @thegreatjedi Is there any way I can improve my answer?

Comment: @thegreatjedi - beady little eyes and a vagina for a mouth. Yep, maybe the Kel Dor and the Predators are cousins.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're happy with an out-of-universe image, this is character actor [Alan Ruscoe](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0750603/) in his makeup, but without his trademark mask covering his mouth and eyes.

[image]

Interestingly, the [Star Wars Databank article on Plo Koon](http://www.starwars.com/plo-koon-biography-gallery) used to contain an image with *just his breather,* however this appears to have now been removed.

[image]